# SQL query use WHERE on a column ALIAS

Tags: sql-server-2008

This should be easy but I'm getting an "Invalid column Name" error.

```
SELECT Transaction, COUNT(ItemId) AS ItemCount
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE ItemCount > 5
GROUP BY Transaction
ORDER BY ItemCount DESC
```

This statement works without the WHERE clause which seems like a double standard to me since ORDER BY is using the column alias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `HAVING` and specify count again

```
SELECT Transaction, COUNT(ItemId) AS ItemCount
FROM TransactionTable
GROUP BY Transaction
HAVING COUNT(ItemId) > 5
ORDER BY ItemCount DESC
```

The reason `ORDER BY` is working with the alias is because a SQL query is processed in this order

FROM (incl joins)
ON
OUTER
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
TOP

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Transaction], COUNT(ItemId) AS ItemCount
FROM TransactionTable
WHERE ItemCount > 5
GROUP BY COUNT(ItemId) 
ORDER BY COUNT(ItemId) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the column alias in the `ORDER BY` as (logically) this is processed after the `SELECT`. To use a column alias in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause you can define the `SELECT` inside a table expression e.g. as below.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Transaction ,
                COUNT(itemid) AS itemcount
         FROM   transactiontable
         GROUP  BY Transaction )
SELECT Transaction ,
       itemcount
FROM   transactiontable
WHERE  itemcount > 5
ORDER  BY itemcount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tempTable AS
(
  SELECT Transaction, COUNT(ItemId) AS ItemCount
  FROM TransactionTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM tempTable
WHERE ItemCount > 5
GROUP BY Transaction
ORDER BY ItemCount DESC
```